# How can I *Efficiently* SUM integers in dynamic number of columns While de-duplicating row data?

Tags: excel, vba

It seems like there must be a really simple/concise way to do this. Below is the atrocity I wrote. It actually works (there were many other looping attempts that didn't) but it's still really clunky and inefficient. Please let me know what you think.

**PROBLEM:**
I need to de-duplicate data from columns A & B while SUM-ing all associated row values in each of remaining columns (Dynamically - those which contain data).
[SAMPLE DATA ATTACHED (Output tab is  the end result I'm hoping to achieve after manipulating the Input)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nJgPFO74PJ7bHxA6nz-Dej8mOsaOGGHW/view?usp=sharing)

**NOTEWORTHY POINTS:**

1. Row count will be dynamic and almost always contain a random number of blank rows between data (Maybe script should start with a sort statement?)
2. Data in columns A & B will be reiterated many times but I'm trying to get to one consolidated row per unique part number (description column B should always match like part numbers as seen in the example)
3. Script must accommodate a dynamic count of columns (Those with header values in Row 1). There could be 3 or 300 uniquely named room columns.

   ```
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'SORT INPUT DATA
       Sheets("Input").Select
       Range("A1").Select
       Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Sort.SortFields.Clear
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A6572") _
           , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
       With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Sort
           .SetRange Range("A1:G6572")
           .Header = xlYes
           .MatchCase = False
           .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
           .SortMethod = xlPinYin
           .Apply
       End With

   'RECREATE MATRIX AT GT2 (DUP SKUs WITH ALL QTYs)
       Range("A2:B2").Select
       Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
       Selection.Copy
       Range("GS2").Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste

           'SHEET RESIZING
           Range("C1").Select
           Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
           Selection.Copy

           Range("GU2").Select
           ActiveSheet.Paste
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
           Selection.ClearContents

       Range("GU2").Select
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
           "=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(R1C3:INDEX(R1,MATCH(""ZZZ"",R1)),R1C[-200])))*(R2C1:INDEX(C1,MATCH(""ZZZ"",C1))=RC201)*R2C3:INDEX(C1:C200,MATCH(""ZZZ"",C1),MATCH(""ZZZ"",R1)))"
       Range("GU2").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste

   'PASTE SPECIAL ONTO OUTPUT

   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

       Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
       Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       Selection.Copy

       Sheets("Output").Select
       Range("B3").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
           :=False, Transpose:=False

   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

       Range("GU2").Select
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "."
       Selection.Copy
       Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
       Range("B2:GU2").Select
       Range("GU2").Activate
       ActiveSheet.Paste

       Sheets("Input").Select
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

   'PASTE HEADERS ONTO OUTPUT
       Range("A1").Select
       Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
       Selection.Copy
       Sheets("Output").Select
       Range("B2").Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste

   'DEDUP OUTPUT
       Range("B2").Select

       Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
       ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2:$GU$4201").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, _
           7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, _
           34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, _
           60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, _
           86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, _
           109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128 _
           , 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, _
           148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167 _
           , 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, _
           187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202), Header:= _
           xlYes

   'CLEAN UP INPUT AND SETTLE ON OUTPUT SHEET
       Sheets("Input").Select
       Range("GS2").Select
       Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
       Selection.Delete

   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   ```

Comment: *'... and loops are throwing me for a loop'* ha-ha, never heard that one before! you should write that down somewhere.

Comment: Seems like you just want to group by columns A and B (excluding blank rows) whilst using `sum` to aggregate -- sort of like a pivot table. I will write some code, if nobody has already submitted an answer by then.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: @jww I'm honestly embarrassed about the number of hours I put in to come up with the following. I edited the posting with what I have that's limping along...

Comment: @chillin Really appreciate your feedback. Sorry if this was unanswerable for a bit (it was unfortunately placed on hold due to the way I originally phrased the question).  As you can see; I'm using a bunch of select statements (I'd like to get away from) and my code is not very dynamic (specifically accounts for only 200 columns).. Any help you could provide is greatly appreciated. I intend to reverse engineer to learn from any answers provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the below work for you? It relies on you being able to access the Scripting.Dictionary object. I used late-binding to save you having to add a reference.

I created some dummy data (based on your Input sheet), ran the code, and it seemed to work for me (I got something that looked like your Output sheet).

```
Option Explicit

Sub groupByAndSum()

    ' Change this sheet to where your data is stored. I assume Sheet1 '
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim topLeftCell As Range
        ' Change this to the cell address where your first header is. I assume A1'
        Set topLeftCell = .Range("A1")

        Dim lastSourceRow As Long
        lastSourceRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, topLeftCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim lastSourceColumn As Long
        lastSourceColumn = .Cells(topLeftCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Dim inputArray() As Variant
        inputArray = .Range(topLeftCell, .Cells(lastSourceRow, lastSourceColumn)).Value2

    End With

    Dim groupKeys As Object
    Set groupKeys = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim Key As String
    Dim rowIndex As Long

    Dim columnIndex As Long

    Const FIRST_NONKEY_COLUMN_INDEX = 3 ' Skip columns A and B
    Const KEY_DELIMITER As String = "!@@!"

    Dim columnCount As Long
    columnCount = UBound(inputArray, 2)

    Dim rowItems() As Long

    ' We use dictionary to get a unique list of keys that we can group columns A and B by.
    For rowIndex = (LBound(inputArray, 1) + 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1) ' (+1) is in order to skip header row.
        For columnIndex = FIRST_NONKEY_COLUMN_INDEX To columnCount

            ' If column A is blank, assume that column B/rest of the row is blank too
            ' and therefore skip entire row
            If Len(inputArray(rowIndex, 1)) > 0 Then
                Key = CStr(inputArray(rowIndex, 1)) & KEY_DELIMITER & CStr(inputArray(rowIndex, 2))

                If Not groupKeys.Exists(Key) Then
                    groupKeys.Add Key, blankArray(FIRST_NONKEY_COLUMN_INDEX, columnCount)
                End If

                ' Think VBA returns dictionary items ByVal rather than ByRef.
                ' So assign item to variable, modify the variable,
                ' Then overwrite item with modified variable to affect/update the dictionary.
                rowItems = groupKeys(Key)
                rowItems(columnIndex) = rowItems(columnIndex) + inputArray(rowIndex, columnIndex)
                groupKeys(Key) = rowItems

            End If

        Next columnIndex
    Next rowIndex

    Dim outputArray() As Variant
    ReDim outputArray(1 To groupKeys.Count, 1 To UBound(inputArray, 2))
    Dim splitKeys() As String

    ' We access via index instead of iterating over keys because we use the same index for accessing outputArray
    ' And also because speed is probably not critical at this stage (as we have fewer rows).
    For rowIndex = 1 To groupKeys.Count
        Key = groupKeys.keys()(rowIndex - 1)  ' Dictionary keys are 0-based.
        splitKeys = VBA.Strings.Split(Key, KEY_DELIMITER, -1, vbBinaryCompare)
        outputArray(rowIndex, 1) = splitKeys(0)
        outputArray(rowIndex, 2) = splitKeys(1)

        rowItems = groupKeys(Key)

        For columnIndex = FIRST_NONKEY_COLUMN_INDEX To columnCount
            outputArray(rowIndex, columnIndex) = rowItems(columnIndex)
        Next columnIndex
    Next rowIndex

    Dim headersRow() As Variant
    headersRow = Application.index(inputArray, 1, 0)

    ' Presently, this will add a new worksheet to the workbook
    ' and write the aggregated data there.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        With .Range("A1")
            .Resize(1, UBound(headersRow, 1)).Value2 = headersRow ' Write headers to sheet.
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(outputArray, 1), UBound(outputArray, 2)).Value2 = outputArray ' Write body (aggregated data) to sheet.
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Private Function blankArray(ByVal lowerBound As Long, ByVal upperBound As Long) As Long()
    Dim outputArray() As Long
    ReDim outputArray(lowerBound To upperBound)

    blankArray = outputArray
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much; this is exactly what I was trying to do and am too green to have figured that out!
I do have one follow-up question. What is the "Private Function" code you added to the bottom used for?

Comment: When looping by row, each time we encounter some new combination of values in column A and B, we initialise a new array of zeros (we can then add the values in column C and so forth to the array). `blankArray` is used to give us this new array each time. You can get rid of the word `Private` (if you want) and it should function just the same (the scope would then implicitly be Public as is presently the case with `groupByAndSum`). Hope this makes sense.